# react-select how to edit created entries

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm using the Select.AsyncCreatable:

```
<Select.AsyncCreatable
      clearableValue={true}
      multi={true}
      scrollMenuIntoView={true}
      name="field-name"
      value={values}
      loadOptions={this.getOptions}
      onChange={value => {
        this.handleOnChange(value...)
      }}
      placeholder={this.defaultPlaceholder}
      />
```

How can I edit options I did create. I can remove created options and reenter them, but is there an option to edit selected values? It would be more comfortable.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am struggling with the same, not sure if the only solution is to dump the whole react-select component?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/1868#issuecomment-325952583 helps.

Comment: @marcel somehow i have managed to edit a single custom tag, check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/49598138

Comment: have you managed to get this working? i need this as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to do it with react-select, but I think what you are looking for is [editable-creatable-multiselect](https://github.com/bordernone/editable-creatable-multiselect)

Here's a demo:

[image]

Answer (score -3):

I really can't find any solution for this so i just modified what i found online and made it editable:

https://codesandbox.io/s/n4nqrjw564

hope it helps.

editing to add the code:

```
import React from "react";

const initialValues = [
  { label: "Test1", value: "Test1" },
  { label: "Test2", value: "Test2" },
  { label: "Test3", value: "Test3" }
];

const createOption = label => ({
  label,
  value: label
});

export default class TagsInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      //value: [],
      value: initialValues,
      focused: false,
      inputValue: ""
    };

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleInputKeyDown = this.handleInputKeyDown.bind(this);
    this.handleEditItem = this.handleEditItem.bind(this);
    this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    const styles = {
      container: {
        border: "1px solid #ddd",
        padding: "5px",
        borderRadius: "5px"
      },

      items: {
        display: "inline-block",
        padding: "2px",
        border: "1px solid black",
        fontFamily: "Helvetica, sans-serif",
        borderRadius: "5px",
        marginRight: "5px",
        cursor: "pointer"
      },

      input: {
        outline: "none",
        border: "none",
        fontSize: "14px",
        fontFamily: "Helvetica, sans-serif"
      }
    };
    return (
      <label>
        <ul style={styles.container}>
          {this.state.value.map((item, i) => (
            <li key={i} style={styles.items} onClick={this.handleEditItem(i)}>
              {item.label}
            </li>
          ))}
          <input
            style={styles.input}
            value={this.state.inputValue}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            onKeyDown={this.handleInputKeyDown}
            onBlur={this.handleBlur}
          />
        </ul>
      </label>
    );
  }

  handleBlur(evt) {
    const { value } = evt.target;

    if (value !== "") {
      this.setState(state => ({
        value: [...state.value, createOption(value)],
        inputValue: ""
      }));
    }

    console.log(this.state.value);
  }

  handleInputChange(evt) {
    this.setState({ inputValue: evt.target.value });
  }

  handleInputKeyDown(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
      const { value } = evt.target;

      if (value !== "") {
        this.setState(state => ({
          value: [...state.value, createOption(value)],
          inputValue: ""
        }));
      }
    }

    if (evt.keyCode === 9) {
      const { value } = evt.target;

      if (value !== "") {
        this.setState(state => ({
          value: [...state.value, createOption(value)],
          inputValue: ""
        }));
      }
    }

    if (
      this.state.value.length &&
      evt.keyCode === 8 &&
      !this.state.inputValue.length
    ) {
      this.setState(state => ({
        value: state.value.slice(0, state.value.length - 1)
      }));
    }

    console.log(this.state.value);
  }

  handleEditItem(index) {
    return () => {
      let it = this.state.value.filter((item, i) => i === index);
      console.log(it);
      this.setState(state => ({
        value: state.value.filter((item, i) => i !== index),
        inputValue: it[0].label
      }));
      //need to change to text box or open a new textbox
    };
  }
}
```