# react-select custom tag edit feature

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm using react-select in my app and it works perfectly but I need a feature when user creates a custom tag, they will edit it which is a valid feature.But in react-select there's no option to edit the custom tag.

I really need this feature in my app, so I have started to do it on my own to edit the custom tags and somehow managed to get it like below :

[image]

This works for a single custom tag and I need this to work for all custom tags .But I'm struck when editing second custom tag, the input field shown in both custom tags.

Code is available [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-select-custom-tag-edit-new)

Any help on this would be helpful. Since many people like me need this feature, any suggestions on this will be helpful.

Comment: have you managed to get this working? i really need this as .well. but i am using https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select

Comment: ended  up using react-select and used http://furqanzafar.github.io/react-selectize/#/  - Tags - Advance usage

Comment: @PageF.P.T I've raised this issue in https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/2490 also, nothing helped much