# React Select Keep Input Value After Selection

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am currently working with `react-select` with single selection. After selecting a particular value, I would like the user to be able to edit the typed in text (not necessarily the same as the rendered option (`formatOptionLabel`).

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-course-dfmn2?file=/src/Selector.tsx

For example, if I typed in `PHYS101`, and then select the option `PHYS101 ... joe`, and then proceed to edit the text, for backspace the form would be come `PHYS10` and if I type `A` then it would be `PHYS101A`.

I attempted to use the `onInputChange` and `onChange` props, but I cannot get it to work consistently. I would appreciate any suggestions or snippets of code I could use.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar issue. Maybe that could help.

Here is a link to the issue. [react-select custom tag edit feature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49598138/14095218)

OR

If you wanna switch over to some other library for your specific purpose.
You could use [react-selectize](http://furqanzafar.github.io/react-selectize/#/?category=simple&example=editable-value).
You can provide props to edit the selected option.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this.

I pulled a reference to the internals via ref

```
<Select
    ref={selectRef}
    onChange={onOptionSelect}
/>
```

and in the useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const selectObj = selectRef?.current
  if (selectedOption?.value && selectObj) {
    selectObj.state.inputValue = selectedOption?.value
  }
 }, [selectedOption])
```

Comment: doing this onFocus doesn't work as work as it will add the value after you have clicked the field